# Find all complex numbers satisfying the equation.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all complex numbers satisfying $\cos(z) = i$.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint** Use the identity $\cos(z)= \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ and then solve the resulting quadratic equation in $e^{iz}.$